# Unable to upload logo in Drupal 7 some error occur also unable to update modules

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to upload logo on Drupal 7 website but getting some error during upload logo and also unable to update any module

please check the error below:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(temporary://logo.png): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1668 of /home/yidemo/mexa.yidemo.in/includes/file.inc).
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpFhLQk6' to 'temporary://Mexa-logo.png' in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1668 of /home/host/subdomain/includes/file.inc).
File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.

Comment: Have you configured your temp folder correctly. If yes then does the folder have permissions so that your server can create temp files in the folder.

Comment: ok, let me check. thanks

Comment: Go to Configuration -> Media -> File system and click "Save configuration". If some field containing temporary files paths gets red outline it means that Drupal can't write files there so you have to fix permissions.

Comment: there is some problem with my server I think that's why I am facing the issue. Thanks